# Не запускается файл .class с командной строки (Error: Could not find or load main class SimpleTest)

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, test-automation

Ситуация такая. Нужно запустить тест на java с помощью командной строки Windows. После компиляции получила файл .class, который не удается запустить. 
Прописываю:
`java -cp C:\Users\Yuliia\IdeaProjects\test1123\classes\com\selenium\test\ SimpleTest`

Выдает:

> Error: Could not find or load main class SimpleTest.

Selenium Standalone server запущен, java установлена. Писала в IntelliJ IDEA IDE.

Код:

```
package com.selenium.test;


import com.selenium.test.webtestsbase.WebDriverFactory;
import com.selenium.test.utils.DOMParser;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;


public class SimpleTest extends TestCase {

    public static final DOMParser DOM_PARSER = new DOMParser();
//    @Rule
//    public ScreenShotOnFailRule screenShotOnFailRule = new ScreenShotOnFailRule();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run(SimpleTest.class);
    }

//    @Before
//    public void beforeTest() {
//        WebDriverFactory.startBrowser(false);
//    }

    @Test
    public void testPages() {
        DOMParser dom = DOM_PARSER;
        dom.Parse_sitemap();
        ArrayList pages = dom.getPages();

        WebDriverFactory.startBrowser(false);

        WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
            String url = pages.get(i).toString();
            driver.get(url);
            String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
            assertFalse("Page was not found on server", driver.getTitle().contains("404"));
            assertFalse("Page was not found on site itself", driver.getPageSource().contains("This page was lost at sea"));
            assertFalse("Page was not found on site itself", bodyText.contains("NOT FOUND"));
        }

        WebDriverFactory.finishBrowser();

    }
```

Попробовала так:  `C:\Users\Yuliia\IdeaProjects\test1123\src\classes\com\selenium\test> java -cp SimpleTest.class`

Выдало:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

**НОВОЕ**

Запускаю:

```
C:\Users\Yuliia\IdeaProjects\test1123>java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.4\lib\*";"C:\Users\Yuliia\Desktop\selenium-2.47.1\*";"C:\Users\Yuliia\Desktop\commons-io-2.4\*";C:\Users\Yuliia\IdeaProjects\test1123\classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.selenium.test.junit.tests.SimpleTest
```

Получаю:

```
JUnit version 4.11
.E
Time: 1.082
There was 1 failure:
1) testPages(com.selenium.test.junit.tests.SimpleTest)
com.selenium.test.exceptions.TestsConfigurationException: Unable to read property file with name 'config.properties' - file not found
        at com.selenium.test.configuration.properties.PropertiesLoader.populate(PropertiesLoader.java:37)
        at com.selenium.test.configuration.TestsConfig.<init>(TestsConfig.java:25)
        at com.selenium.test.configuration.TestsConfig.getConfig(TestsConfig.java:19)
        at com.selenium.test.webtestsbase.WebDriverFactory.startBrowser(WebDriverFactory.java:46)
        at com.selenium.test.junit.tests.SimpleTest.testPages(SimpleTest.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:96)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:47)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:40)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Comment: Ну а по факту - у тебя нет public static void main(String ... args) метода в этом SimpleTest

Comment: @AndrewBystrov куда, что, как? это мой первый тест и первый опыт запуска через командную строку.

Comment: @Юлия Приведите минимальный пример кода для воспроизведения ошибки. Так будет понятнее, что у вас не так и можно будет аргументировать ответы.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov  public static void main(String[] args) {
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run(SimpleTest.class);
    }

Это есть.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev добавила код

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev попробовала по другому - появилось длинное сообщение - добавила в вопрос

Comment: Получилось ли теперь запустить тест или проблема всё ещё актуальна?

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev спасибо большое за ответ! У меня не все так быстро) я в процессе. как только сделаю - отпишусь!

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev Новая беда. Не видит config.properties. Добавила в вопрос

Comment: Код в задании ещё актуален или был изменён? Если был изменён, внесите обновлённый код перед добавленной информацией.

Comment: Вероятно, стоит также включить в вопрос структуру каталогов проекта

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev Все работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, рекомендуется использовать написание тестов в стиле JUnit 4, т.е. без наследования от TestCase, а используя аннотацию `@Test`.

Для описания того, как нужно запускать тест в вашем случае, разберу сначала пример с использованием синтаксиса JUnit 3.

Имеется проект со следующей структурой файлов:

```
my_project/
--junit.jar
--hamcrest-core.jar
--com/
----prog/
------MyTest.java
```

**junit.jar** и **hamcrest-core.jar** -- это файлы библиотеки JUnit.

Содержимое файла **my_project/com/prog/MyTest.java**:

```
package com.prog;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class MyTest extends TestCase {
    public void testSum() {
        assertEquals(3, 1 + 2);
    }
}
```

Скомпилировать его можно следующим образом:
`my_project> javac -cp .;junit.jar my_project\com\prog\MyTest.java`

*Для Windows используется разделитель путей `;` и желателен символ `\` для каталогов.*
*Для Linux разделитель путей `:` и символ `/` для каталогов.*

После этого появится файл **my_project/com/prog/MyTest.class**.

Для запуска тестов этого файла из командной строки нужно использовать следующую команду:
`my_project> java -cp .;junit.jar;hamcrest-core.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.prog.MyTest`

После этого будет показано сообщение об успешном прохождении тестов.

```
.
Time: 0,001

OK (1 test)
```

---

Для JUnit версии 4 код тестов немного изменится. **my_project/com/prog/MyTest.java**:

```
package com.prog;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        assertEquals(3, 1 + 2);
    }
}
```

Изменится и запуск тестов:

```
my_project> java -cp .;junit.jar;hamcrest-core.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.prog.MyTest
```

Результат запуска:

```
JUnit version 4.12
.
Time: 0,004

OK (1 test)
```

---

Источник:

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started